# Properties vs variables - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me the difference between these? I started noticing some behaviours that i was not expecting.

```
let myObj = {  _name:"Consala",
             get name(){
                  return `Mr. ${this._name}`  }}
```

Why does this require the *this* keyword because i thought functions have access to all variables surrounding them.

I explained this by saying that variables are different from properties and there is no variable called `_name` inside of the myObj just a property. Im not sure if this is correct though.

I tried to test this theory using this:

```
    let test = "banana"
print(test) //prints banana
print(this.test) //prints undefined
this.test = "apple"
print(this.test) //prints apple
```

I thought this confirmed what i thought because when undefined was printed i explained it as there is no property called test on the global object showing me there is a difference between variables and properties.

But then i changed `let` to `var` and then print(this.test) also prints banana instead of undefined...

Whats going on here?

Im pretty confused but im thinking that when you use var you are setting a property to the object its in (which would explain why var has function scope right?) but then what happens when you use let?

**I hope people dont think of this as a low effort post because i have really been trying to figure this one out on my own rather than just refusing to think for myself. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `var` prints `banana` instead of `undefined` is because you have declared it outside of all functions so it takes global scope.

> The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context and closures thereof, which is either the enclosing function and functions declared within it, or, for variables declared outside any function, global.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

On the other hand, let is block scoped so it gives you `undefined`

And to answer your question about why we need `this`, it is because the `name` getter function has no variable called `_name` in its scope.
Thus it needs `this` to indicate to it to use the object scope to look for the `_name` variable

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this link back to properties? Was i incorrect saying that var will set properties in the object its in? And why must we use the this keyword when accessing properties of an object that ist already inside of?

Comment: @SidTurner I have updated the answer to address your question about using ```this```. var is used for variables, it has no correlation with object properties.

Answer (score 0):

**this** keyword is the most confusing keyword in JavaScript. It's not because it's kind of buggy or what but it's because developers think it will work in the same way as it does in other languages but that's not true.
**this** has dynamic scope. Dynamic scoping does not care how the code is written, but instead how it executes. So the value of this depends on how is it executed.
Talking about your first example

```
let myObj = {  _name:"Consala",
             get name(){
                  return `Mr. ${this._name}`  }}
```

In this case, when you call that function you type `myObj.name` which binds myObj as `this` to name. So whenever you call a function using [Object Name].[function] you assign this object as the function's `this`.

Let's come to the second scenario. I assume you tried that in your browser.
In the case of Browser, `this` refers to window Object (Try console.log(this) ).
What happens there is when you declare a variable using `let` it doesn't add to `Window` object but when you declare it using `var` keyword, it adds to `Window` Object.
Try declaring a Variable using var and then do `console.log(this)`. You will find that variable in `Window` Object but in case of a variable declared using `let` won't be there.